# In Mathematica 13.3 are chat notebooks enabled by default?

Tags: notebooks, chatai

I read that Mathematica 13.3 supports chat notebooks. I have installed Mathematica 13.3 but do not see a way to create chat-enabled notebooks. Do I need to enable it? If it is enabled by default, on the other hand, how do I create chat-enabled notebook?

Comment: Following https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/

The website states "The most immediately visible LLM tech in Version 13.3 is Chat Notebooks. Go to File > New > Chat-Enabled Notebook and you’ll get a Chat Notebook".

Comment: @Moo It is not there.

Comment: Do iit when you first start Mathematica -- before launching a normal notebook.

Comment: It wasn't enabled when I started up version 13.3 the first time. I found a new entry in the Preferences: "AI Settings". When I opened this up, it auto-downloaded the paclet and the chat notebooks were available as options after relaunching. You can also manually download the paclet as described in the answer below.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone find the "PlotHighlighting" option in the "Plot" function working? It seems that version 13.3 has some 'bugs'. I've tried on two Windows 11 laptops and another Windows 10 laptop and still have the same issues.

Answer (score 7):

The chat enabled notebook wasn't immediately visible in 13.3 (Win) for me either. Loading this paclet fixed it (more information here [Wolfram Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/Chatbook/)):

```
PacletInstall["Wolfram/Chatbook"]
```

Then

```
Needs["Wolfram`Chatbook`"]
```

You'll still need to obtain an OpenAI key (the chat notebook will prompt for this) to access LLM functionality. There may be some further steps needed to access the Wolfram OpenAI plugin

Comment: Thank you. Yes but, why I need to install paclet if it is "supported by Mathematica"? Is there something wrong with my Mathematica installation or this is for everyone that way?

Comment: @vasili111 I don't know, it's probably a question better put to Wolfram Research

Answer (score 2):

No, you use Alt+N to create a new chat notebook. One thing to be aware of is if you have a long chat notebook you can exceed the token limit, so it's good to use ~ to split the notebook up so the OPENAI API isn't overwhelmed.

Stephen Wolfram writes in his blog post [Introducing Chat Notebooks: Integrating LLMs into the Notebook Paradigm](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/introducing-chat-notebooks-integrating-llms-into-the-notebook-paradigm/) in the section [Who Are You Gonna Talk To?](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/introducing-chat-notebooks-integrating-llms-into-the-notebook-paradigm#who-are-you-gonna-talk-to?)

> We mentioned in passing above that when there are two kinds of Chat
> Notebooks you can create (e.g. with the File > New menu): Chat-Enabled
> Notebooks and Chat-Driven Notebooks. In future versions of the Wolfram
> Notebook system, Chat-Enabled Notebooks will probably be the standard
> default for all new notebooks, but for now it’s something you have to
> explicitly choose.

I'm not sure if chat notebooks will be the default in 13.4, 13.5, or later in 14.

Comment: Hello, when I do I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWLqu.jpg;  do you know a workaround? Cheers, Chris

Comment: I can't reach that site. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWLqu.jpg

Comment: It basically says : A You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
Failure Message: Rate limit reached for requests. Please try again later.
Tag:
ChatbookAction::RateLimitReached

Comment: @chris Same for me, I always get this error message